# Function defined in .emacs does not start automatically

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've just started using [Fill Column Indicator](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillColumnIndicator) for Emacs, which adds a vertical line on  editing window to indicate the fill column.

I figured out that `turn-on-fci-mode` function could trigger the the bar.
I wanted it to start at the time when Emacs starts, so I also included it in the .emacs file.

The changes in the .emacs files are as follows:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/custom")
(require 'fill-column-indicator) 
(turn-on-fci-mode)
```

Unfortunately, the line does not come up, even though running the function manually brings up the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fci-mode` is buffer local. That means you need to turn it on for each buffer individually - setting it in your .emacs will set for one buffer, possibly just the splash screen, and not have any influence on the rest of your buffers.

To turn it on for all buffers, you need to use the following code in `.emacs`:

```el
(define-globalized-minor-mode global-fci-mode fci-mode (lambda () (fci-mode 1)))
  (global-fci-mode 1)
```

Comment: thanks, that did it. I had a doubt though. Why is `fci-mode` turned on for all the buffers when I do `M-x fci-mode`, if it's only defined for local buffer.

Comment: I'm not sure of the particulars for this mode, I haven't used it myself, sorry!